# Background job in Qiskit not showing output on .ipynb file?

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I've successfully run jobs to measure circuits on Qiskit (Shor's algorithm for $N=15$ or simpler). However, it appears when I close out of everything and leave, the output of the job doesn't show in the .ipynb, even when the job shows as "complete". It must be that the notebook server shuts down when I leave.

Do I really need to leave it open and wait for the job to complete in order to see output?